# Macro to copy a row with an empty cell in any of the last 5 columns to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

As stated above, I'm trying to write a program that looks at the last 5 columns of every row in Sheet2 and copies that row if any of the cells in those last 5 columns are empty, then pastes the row into a new sheet Sheet3. I've been searching and found some helpful links but I keep getting an "Object required" error. I have a feeling I forgot something simple but I'm not getting anywhere. This is my 2nd day attempting macros, I appreciate any help!

```
Sub missingDataCopy()


Dim startColumn As Integer
Dim startRow As Integer

Dim totalRows As Integer
Dim totalColumns As Integer

Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim currentRow As Integer

Dim shouldCopyRow As Boolean

Dim j As Long

startColumn = 7
totalColumns = 11
startRow = 1
j = 1
totalRows = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, startColumn).End(xlUp).Row


For currentRow = totalRows To startRow Step -1
    shouldCopyRow = False


    For currentColumn = startColumn To totalColumns
        If IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn)) Then
            shouldCopyRow = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If shouldCopyRow Then
        Sheet2.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
```

Comment: Try `totalRows = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, startColumn).End(xlUp).Row`. If that doesn't help then please include in your post on which line you are getting the aforementioned error.

Comment: Tried your addition but still get the same error (object required). The debugger highlights that line as the one where the error is occurring.

Comment: Which line is highlighted when you get the error?

Comment: `totalRows = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, startColumn).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting indicates that there is not `Sheet` in your Excel file with the `CodeName` `Sheet2`. Have a look at the following illustration to see the distinction between the `Name` of a sheet (which you see in the tab) and the `CodeName`:

[image]

If you wish to code with the `CodeName` then you must change it in the VBE as shown above. Alternatively you can also use the `Name` of the sheet. But then your line should read:

```
totalRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, startColumn).End(xlUp).Row
```

<sub>Because the name of the sheet in the above example is `Sheet1`.</sub>

Comment: Thank you Ralph! I made the change and still get an error but it is on a later line: `Sheet4.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A" & j)` it is a "subscript out of range" error

Comment: That's because `Sheet4` is also a `CodeName`. Change it as shown above or make sure that the sheet you want to refer to has this `CodeName`.

Comment: Got it! I realized I had mixed my referencing and put "Sheet5" in quotes where it was named Sheet3 on the tab, so changed to "Sheet3" and it works! Thanks for your help.