# Sheet codename is not recognized

Tags: vba, excel

In my code, i use the codename of some sheet.

The problem is, that when i execute the macro by using a form, it does not recognize the codename (the variable recives a null value).

what could be the reason for that?

```
 Dim sCodeName As String

 ' Get the codename of the newly created sheet
 sCodeName = Worksheets(atar).CodeName
```

'atar' is a variable containing the name of one of my sheets.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure why you're trying to store the `CodeName` of a sheet in a string variable. Yet, you can easily verify the outcome of the above line by replacing `sCodeName =` with `MsgBox` like so `MsgBox Worksheets(atar).CodeName`. If there is a sheet with the name stored in `atar` then you'll get to see the `CodeName` in a message box. If there is no such sheet you'll get an error message. BTW, the following illustration might be helpful in identifying the code name of any given sheet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42815407/1153513

Answer (score 1):

Go to the code view, to the left you see your VBA project with its sheets and modules. Select the sheet in question and look at the property window.

You see a field called "(Name)" and one called "Name".
"(Name)" is the code name, "Name" is the sheet name. Now compare the code name with your output.

**Edit**:
@Ralph was faster and provided a nice picture with the exact same information.

Answer (score 0):

**Using a Function to Check for the Existence of a Code Name**

```
Function WorksheetCodeNameExists(wb As Workbook, sCodeName As String) As Boolean 
    Dim s As String 
    Dim ws As Worksheet 

    WorksheetCodeNameExists = False 
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets 
        If StrComp(ws.CodeName, sCodeName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 
            WorksheetCodeNameExists = True 
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next 
    Set ws = Nothing 
End Function
```